# Trying to put div in the middle of other div without success

Tags: html, css

I search alot in the website but didn't find solution.
Im trying to display text when someone hover image, so what I do is:

```css
.seeImage {
  background: black;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 475px;
  height: 36ppx;
}
.seeImage img {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.hoverimg {
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.seeImage:hover .hoverimg {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="seeImage">
  <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png">
  <div class="hoverimg">
    <p>Text text</p>
    <p>More text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have two paragraphs on a div that have the class "hoverimg", and the paragraphs displaying after 50%, (they aren't in the middle, they after the middle of the image).

Someone have reasons why is it? I guess I can fix it by margin-top: (negative)px, but if i need to cut or add more content, I will always should to update the margin again, so someone know how to do it without using margin?

Thanks in advance!

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p6ybpahq/20/
I want that the text that displayed when hover the image, will be in the middle of the image

Comment: Add your HTML and the rest of the CSS.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle @PaulRedmond

Comment: @Roy http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312545

Comment: Your HTML structure is incorrect. Close the `</div>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.seeImage {
  background: black;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.seeImage img {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.hoverimg {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.seeImage:hover .hoverimg {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="seeImage">
  <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png">
  <div class="hoverimg">
    <p>Text text</p>
    <p>More text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` for centering the element vertically and horizontally.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/p6ybpahq/28/)

Comment: Thats showing the text in the bottom left of the image

Comment: @Roy The answer is updated.

Comment: same... I want that the text will be in the middle and center

Comment: @Roy Check again. You forgot to give `position:relative` to the parent element.

Comment: Thanks! You helped me alot!

Comment: @Roy You are welcome. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS

```
.seeImage {
    background: black;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 475px;
    height: 36ppx;
    position: relative;  //Added this
}

.seeImage img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.hoverimg {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.seeImage:hover .hoverimg {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is completely different, but I suggest using the image as a background image and centering it based on that background images width and height. The top and left of the text are 45% instead of 50% because you need to account for the texts width and height for it to be centered.

```
.hoverimg {
    background: url(http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png) no-repeat;
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    position:relative;
}
.text{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:45%;
  left:45%;
}
.hoverimg:hover .text{
  display:block;
}

<div class="seeImage">
    <div class="hoverimg">
    <div class="text">
      <p>Text text</p>
      <p>More text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p6ybpahq/29/